# valgrind only runs from root directory

Tags: shell, path, zsh

Im not sure how to fix this; I can't run valgrind from anywhere but my root directory; i.e. I have to type the entire pathname of the program I want to run through valgrind while im in my root directory.

```
% : /
 >>> valgrind
valgrind: no program specified
valgrind: Use --help for more information.

% : /
 >[1]> projects

% : /projects
 >>> valgrind
zsh: command not found: valgrind

% : /projects
 >[127]>  type -a valgrind
valgrind not found

% : /projects
 >[1]> /

% : /
 >>>  type -a valgrind
valgrind is usr/local/bin/valgrind

% : /
 >>> echo $path
usr/local/bin /usr/local/sbin /usr/bin /usr/sbin /bin /sbin ~/library/scripts /library/scripts
```

Update: a couple of other things I tried.

```
% : /projects
 >[1]>  /usr/loca/bin/valgrind
zsh: no such file or directory:  /usr/loca/bin/valgrind

% : /
 >>> /usr/local/bin/valgrind
valgrind: no program specified
valgrind: Use --help for more information.
```

Comment: Don't you by some chance have directory-dependent settings of something? Try `type -a valgrind` and `echo $path` while you are IN the `/projects` directory.

Comment: `$path` is the same in `/projects`. How would I go about finding out if I have directory-dependent settings somewhere / where should I look?

Comment: If `$path` looks the same than that's not it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first entry in your `$path` is lacking leading `/`, so it ends up being interpreted as relative path. Which exists only when you are in root. You need to add the leading slash.

I presume you added the paths yourself, so you'll hopefully know where to fix it.